# Any decent "html design" plugin available for use in a website?

Tags: presentation, visual-web-gui

I have a need of allowing visitors to my site to create their own "popup" screens.

I would like to have a WYSIWYG like interface where they can add images, backgrounds, text and move it around, resize, etc. Kind of like building a PowerPoint slide really...

Is there any plugin that can offer such function?
I've been Googling like crazy but can only find "big" solutions which I can't incorporate in my own web-site or "desktop" versions...

Something like this: http://framebox.org/
Although as a jQuery plugin or other simple to adapt plugin framework.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Anders

Comment: what kind of "big" solutions did you find?

Comment: Things like SlideRocket, Prezi, Empressr and so on... Maquetta is nice but too advanced. I only need something that can add a few DIV's with different looks and to be able to move the stuff around and style it abit...

Comment: http://framebox.org/ This would be pretty much what I need, but as a plugin (jQuery preferably)